Trying to configure a Java web application in Eclipse to run in JBoss
My team uses Eclipse Neon to develop Java web apps. JBoss is the application server. I joined the team recently and I have not worked with Eclipse and JBoss before.
Our JBoss is RedHat 7.1.
I was given a .zip archive with JBoss which I was instructed to unzip and place in some folder. Then I created a workspace in Eclipse Neon and imported the Java web application I have to work on into this workspace. My project lead added this JBoss to the workspace and started it successfully. Then he added a library to the project Java Build Path and pointed to the root folder with JBoss. Eclipse is showing this library as RedHat JBoss 7.1 Runtime.
Then I was able to publish the application to JBoss, started it and it worked.
Several days later I was assigned to work on another Java web application. I created a new worspace in Eclipse, imported this project into it, then I set up the same JBoss in this workspace  and started it. Then I added a library in the Java Build Path pointing to the same JBoss root folder. For whatever reason the library is displayed by Eclipse with a somewhat different name:
RedHat JBoss 7.1 EAP Runtime.
Then I tried to deploy this project in JBoss but it would not deploy; in the console tab of Eclipse I see error messages: the server complaints about some JNDI.
Any idea what I did wrong?

Provide the exact error messages in the console especially if they reference specific JNDI resource names or bindings
